# How can I improve my Neural Network accucary ( Speaker Recognition - MFCC )

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, identity, voice-recognition, mfcc

Im working on a speaker recognition Neural Network.

What I am doing is taking wav files [ of the Bing Bang Theory first espiode :-) ], than convert it to MFCC coeffs than I make it as an input to an open source api of Neural Network (MLPClassifier) and as output I define a unique vector to each speaker ( Let's say : [1,0,0,0] - sheldon; [0,1,0,0] - Penny; and ect... ), I take 50 random values for testing and the others for fitting ( training )

This is my code, At the begining I got about random accucary for the NN but after some help of amazing guy I improved it to ~42% but I want more :) about 70% :

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import python_speech_features
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from random import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import randint
import random
winner = []  # this array count how much Bingo we had when we test the NN
random_winner = []
win_len = 0.04  # in seconds
step = win_len / 2
nfft = 2048
for TestNum in tqdm(range(20)):  # in every round we build NN with X,Y that out of them we check 50 after we build the NN
    X = []
    Y = []
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("FinalAudios/") if isfile(join("FinalAudios/", f))]   # Files in dir
    names = []  # names of the speakers
    for file in onlyfiles:  # for each wav sound
        # UNESSECERY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE
        if " " not in file.split("_")[0]:
            names.append(file.split("_")[0])
        else:
            names.append(file.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0])
    only_speakers = [] + names
    #print only_speakers
    names = list(dict.fromkeys(names))  # names of speakers
    print names
    vector_names = []  # vector for each name
    i = 0
    vector_for_each_name = [0] * len(names)
    for name in names:
        vector_for_each_name[i] += 1
        vector_names.append(np.array(vector_for_each_name))
        vector_for_each_name[i] -= 1
        i += 1
    for f in onlyfiles:
        if " " not in f.split("_")[0]:
            f_speaker = f.split("_")[0]
        else:
            f_speaker = f.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0]
        fs, audio = wav.read("FinalAudios/" + f)  # read the file
        try:
            mfcc_feat = python_speech_features.mfcc(audio, samplerate=fs, winlen=win_len,
                                               winstep=step, nfft=nfft, appendEnergy=False)
            flat_list = [item for sublist in mfcc_feat for item in sublist]
            X.append(np.array(flat_list))
            Y.append(np.array(vector_names[names.index(f_speaker)]))
        except IndexError:
            pass
    Z = list(zip(X, Y))

    shuffle(Z)  # WE SHUFFLE X,Y TO PERFORM RANDOM ON THE TEST LEVEL

    X, Y = zip(*Z)
    X = list(X)
    Y = list(Y)
    X = np.asarray(X)
    Y = np.asarray(Y)

    Y_test = Y[:50]  # CHOOSE 50 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    X_test = X[:50]
    X = X[50:]
    Y = Y[50:]
    print len(X)
    clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=3e-2, hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 20), random_state=2)  # create the NN
    clf.fit(X, Y)  # Train it
    print list(clf.predict_proba([X[0]])[0])
    print list(Y_test[0])
    for sample in range(len(X_test)):  # add 1 to winner array if we correct and 0 if not, than in the end it plot it
        arr = list(clf.predict([X_test[sample]])[0])
        if arr.index(max(arr)) == list(Y_test[sample]).index(1):
            winner.append(1)
        else:
            winner.append(0)
        if only_speakers[randint(0, len(only_speakers) - 1)] == only_speakers[randint(0, len(only_speakers) - 1)]:
            random_winner.append(1)
        else:
            random_winner.append(0)

# plot winner
plot_x = []
plot_y = []
for i in range(1, len(winner)):
    plot_y.append(sum(winner[0:i])*1.0/len(winner[0:i]))
    plot_x.append(i)
plot_random_x = []
plot_random_y = []
for i in range(1, len(random_winner)):
    plot_random_y.append(sum(random_winner[0:i])*1.0/len(random_winner[0:i]))
    plot_random_x.append(i)
plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, 'r', label='machine learning')
plt.plot(plot_random_x, plot_random_y, 'b', label='random')
plt.xlabel('Number Of Samples')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('Success Rate')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Success Rate : Random Vs ML!')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

This is my zip file that contains the code and the audio file : https://ufile.io/eggjm1gw

**Somebody have an idea how can I improve my accucary**?

***Edit :***

I improved my data set and put convolution model and got 60% accucarry, which is ok but also not good enoguh

```
import python_speech_features
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
import os
import shutil
from os.path import isfile, join
from random import shuffle
from matplotlib import pyplot
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import randint
import tensorflow as tf
from ast import literal_eval as str2arr
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
#win_len = 0.04  # in seconds
#step = win_len / 2
#nfft = 2048
win_len = 0.05  # in seconds
step = win_len
nfft = 16384
results = []
outfile_x = None
outfile_y = None
winner = []

for TestNum in tqdm(range(40)):  # We check it several times
    if not outfile_x:  # if path not exist we create it
        X = []  # inputs
        Y = []  # outputs
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("FinalAudios") if isfile(join("FinalAudios", f))]   # Files in dir
        names = []  # names of the speakers
        for file in onlyfiles:  # for each wav sound
            # UNESSECERY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE
            if " " not in file.split("_")[0]:
                names.append(file.split("_")[0])
            else:
                names.append(file.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0])
        only_speakers = [] + names
        namesWithoutDuplicate = list(dict.fromkeys(names))
        namesWithoutDuplicateCopy = namesWithoutDuplicate[:]
        for name in namesWithoutDuplicateCopy:  # we remove low samples files
            if names.count(name) < 107:
                namesWithoutDuplicate.remove(name)
        names = namesWithoutDuplicate
        print(names)  # print it
        vector_names = []  # output for each name
        i = 0
        for name in names:
            vector_for_each_name = i
            vector_names.append(np.array(vector_for_each_name))
            i += 1
        for f in onlyfiles:  # for all the files
            if " " not in f.split("_")[0]:
                f_speaker = f.split("_")[0]
            else:
                f_speaker = f.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0]
            if f_speaker in namesWithoutDuplicate:
                fs, audio = wav.read("FinalAudios\\" + f)  # read the file
                try:
                    # compute MFCC
                    mfcc_feat = python_speech_features.mfcc(audio, samplerate=fs, winlen=win_len, winstep=step, nfft=nfft, appendEnergy=False)
                    #flat_list = [item for sublist in mfcc_feat for item in sublist]
                    # Create output + inputs
                    for i in mfcc_feat:
                        X.append(np.array(i))
                        Y.append(np.array(vector_names[names.index(f_speaker)]))
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            else:
                if not os.path.exists("TooLowSamples"):  # if path not exist we create it
                    os.makedirs("TooLowSamples")
                shutil.move("FinalAudios\\" + f, "TooLowSamples\\" + f)
        outfile_x = TemporaryFile()
        np.save(outfile_x, X)
        outfile_y = TemporaryFile()
        np.save(outfile_y, Y)



    # ------------------- RANDOMIZATION, UNNECESSARY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE ------------------- #
    else:
        outfile_x.seek(0)
        X = np.load(outfile_x)
        outfile_y.seek(0)
        Y = np.load(outfile_y)
    Z = list(zip(X, Y))
    shuffle(Z)  # WE SHUFFLE X,Y TO PERFORM RANDOM ON THE TEST LEVEL
    X, Y = zip(*Z)
    X = list(X)
    Y = list(Y)
    lenX = len(X)
    # ------------------- RANDOMIZATION, UNNECESSARY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE ------------------- #
    y_test = np.asarray(Y[:4000])   # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_test = np.asarray(X[:4000])   # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_train = np.asarray(X[4000:])  # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    y_train = np.asarray(Y[4000:])  # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_val = x_train[-4000:]         # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    y_val = y_train[-4000:]         # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    x_train = x_train[:-4000]       # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    y_train = y_train[:-4000]       # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    x_train = x_train.reshape(np.append(x_train.shape, (1, 1)))  # RESHAPE FOR INPUT
    x_test = x_test.reshape(np.append(x_test.shape, (1, 1)))     # RESHAPE FOR INPUT
    x_val = x_val.reshape(np.append(x_val.shape, (1, 1)))  # RESHAPE FOR INPUT
    features_shape = x_val.shape

    # -------------- OUR TENSOR FLOW NEURAL NETWORK MODEL -------------- #
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(name='inputs', shape=(13, 1, 1), dtype='float32'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1, name='block1_conv', input_shape=(13, 1, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='block1_pool'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name='block1_norm'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1, name='block2_conv',
                               input_shape=(13, 1, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block2_pool'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name='block2_norm'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1, name='block3_conv',
                               input_shape=(13, 1, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block3_pool'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name='block3_norm'),

        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name='dense_norm'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='dropout'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='pred')

    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    # -------------- OUR TENSOR FLOW NEURAL NETWORK MODEL -------------- #

    print("fitting")
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    print("testing")
    results.append(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)[1])
    print(results)
    print(sum(results)/len(results))
    for i in range(10000):
        f_1 = only_speakers[randint(0, len(only_speakers) - 1)]
        f_2 = only_speakers[randint(0, len(only_speakers) - 1)]
        if " " not in f_1.split("_")[0]:
            f_speaker_1 = f_1.split("_")[0]
        else:
            f_speaker_1 =f_1.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0]
        if " " not in f_2.split("_")[0]:
            f_speaker_2 = f_2.split("_")[0]
        else:
            f_speaker_2 =f_2.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0]
        if f_speaker_2 == f_speaker_1:
            winner.append(1)
        else:
            winner.append(0)
    print(sum(winner)/len(winner))
    #]
    # if onlyfiles[randint(len(onlyfiles) - 1)] == onlyfiles[randint(len(onlyfiles) - 1)]
    #pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
    #pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')                                          Q
    #pyplot.legend()
    #pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readin your post these are the following things I could suggest you fix/explore

- 42% is not that impressive of an accuracy for the task you have at hand, consider the way you are **cross-validating** e.g. how do you split between a validation, test and training dataset
- Your dataset seems very limited. Your task is to identify the speaker. A single episode might not be enough data for this task.
- You might want to consider Deep Neural Network libraries such as Keras and Tensorflow. Convolutions is something you can apply directly to the MFC Graph.
- If you decide using Tensorflow or Keras consider Triplet-Loss, where you preset a positive and negative example.
- Consider reading the current state of the art for your task: https://github.com/grausof/keras-sincnet
- Consider reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832 and adopting it for speech recognition.

**The easiest thing you can do to improve your results is adding CNN layers to extract features from the MFCC**

Comment: Thanks, I will try and if it work I’ll approved your answear. Just one little question - just for my understanding you want that I will use instead Mlpcalssifier a NN with some hiddens layers that part of them will be a convolution hidden layers?

Comment: Try CNN on MFCC (add 4 or so CNN layers followed by Max Pooling) -> Flatten -> Dense Layers 

This is a very generic architecture that works for most tasks of this nature

Comment: Hi, thanks for answear... can you please look at my edit?

Comment: Try 2d conv. not 1d. The MFCC has 2d structure

Comment: Hi, it's realy imrpoved my precentage to 60%, do you have more suggestions?

Comment: you can look at my edit if you want to see my new code

Comment: I saw you wrote something about triplet loss, how can I input negative values to the machine, will creating a syntetic audios like siri does and input it to the machine learning with output that doesn't represent any of the speakers will help ?

Comment: anyway I very appreciate your answear and the fact that it helped me to improve my accucarry gave you an approve to the answear

Comment: btw , mfcc ouput is 2d ( nX13 ) matrix, do you know if i need to insert any row ( 1x13 )  in the matrix for input or all the matrix together meaning if i have mfcc that his matrix is - [[1,2,3,4,5,6...,13],[2,4,6,...,26]] should i fit the neural network when x_training[0] = [1,2,3,..,13], x_training[1] = [2,4,6,..,26], y_training[0] = speaker = y_training[1] OR x_training[0] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6...,13],[2,4,6,...,26]], y_training[0] = sepaker

Comment: Try searching for wavenet, and triplet loss. You can implement triplet loss easier in your existing model.